# RGB888 as input to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspivid, video-input

I need to give RGB888 data coming from one of my hardware into a Raspberry Pi and should be able to see the video feed via a script just like raspivid. Methods to interface Pi to DPI is available. I need the exactly opposite solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101175/discussion-on-question-by-suraj-raju-rgb888-as-input-to-raspberry-pi).